Expressing $x^2-2y^2$ as sum of 2 squares: is the equation $169^2 - 2 \cdot 80^2 = 119^2 + 40^2$ a coincidence?
Is there a general method for expressing $x^2 - 2y^2$ as a sum of 2 squares when we know for some reason that it must be possible?
I was solving a problem for which once you get to the end, you're asked to express the answer as a sum of 2 squares. I got to $169^2 - 2 \cdot 80^2$ and couldn't continue. Instead, I expanded it to $p = 15761,$ found that $p$ is prime, and used the usual quadratic residue algorithm to express $p$ as a sum of squares.
With the answer in mind, we can use the power of hindsight bias to notice that $169^2 - 120^2$ is a perfect square. This leads to the general observation that if $y$ is even and $x^2 - (3y/2)^2 = z^2,$ then $x^2 - 2y^2 = z^2 + (y/2)^2.$
But what if we don't have hindsight bias and $x, y$ are much larger? Is there a general method for spotting what to subtract and add so that we get a sum of squares?

Do you only want to find the squares or factorize the nuumber $x^2-2y^2$ ?

@Peter, I don't think OP wants to factor $x^2-2y^2$ in the usual sense of the word, which is to express it as a product (in a non-trivial way). Instead, I think OP wants to partition $x^2-2y^2$. Of course, this is very easy to do in a bunch of ways, hence the requirement "as a sum of two squares" to make the problem interesting.

@Peter The squares. I don't think I even used the word factor except for a single typo which I just fixed

You wrote Is there a general method for factorizing $x^2-2y^2$ (see the edit history). I think this is why Peter made his comment. And yes, there is a way to find integer solutions to $x^2-2y^2=z^2+w^2$, using Pell's equation and Fermat's result on the sum of two squares.

According to OEIS sequence A155562,
nonnegative integer $N$ can be expressed as both $x^2 + y^2$ and $z^2 - 2 w^2$ iff there exist nonnegative integers $p,q,r,s$ such that
$$
\eqalign{N &= (p^2-q^2-2 r s)^2+(r^2-s^2-2 p q)^2
\cr &= (p^2+q^2+r^2+s^2)^2-2 (p r+p s+q r-q s)^2}$$

@DietrichBurde That's the typo which I fixed. Nowhere else did I use the word

Right, but Peter made the comment immediately, reading your typo.

It is not true that $x^2-2y^2$ is always a sum of two squares. Consider
$$
3^2-2\cdot 1^2=7,
$$
which is not the sum of two squares.
On the other hand, we can consider integer solutions to the Diophantine equation
$$
x^2-2y^2=z^2+w^2.
$$
For the RHS and LHS we know which integers are the sum of two squares, respectively of the form $x^2-2y^2$, see here, for example:
Is there any variation known to the sum of two squares theorem?
